# NP-completeness of vertex cover

Tags: np-complete, proof-techniques, satisfiability, 3-sat

> Show that the following language is NP-complete
>   $$ L = \{ \langle G,k \rangle \mid \text{$G$ is a graph with a set $S$ of $k$ vertices hitting every edge of $G$}\}. $$

I know I should reduce the problem to SAT. But how I can do it?

Comment: The point with this kind of question is to give you practice in constructing reductions. Getting somebody else to do it for you completely negates the benefit. Hint: the problem you're working with is called "vertex cover".

Comment: Vertex cover is a classical NP-hard problem. You can read a proof of its NP-hardness in Karp's 1972 paper *Reducibility among combinatorial problems*.

Answer (score 1):

A related, but different problem is **Independent Set**: it asks for a set of $k$ vertices that hits each edge *at most* once (instead of *at least* once).

A simple reduction from 3-SAT to Independent Set is as follows:

1. For each clause, we take a clique on $3$ vertices (i.e., a triangle). Each vertex of this triangle corresponds to specific literal appearing in a clause. E.g., a clause $(x_1\vee \neg x_2 \vee x_3)$ would have vertices corresponding to literals $x_1,\neg x_2,x_3$.
2. Whenever two vertices correspond to conflicting literals, we make those vertices adjacent. E.g., all vertices corresponding to $x_1$ are made adjacent to all vertices corresponding to $\neg x_1$.

We now ask whether an independent set of size $m$ (the number of clauses) exists.

Note that since there is a partition of the graph into $m$ cliques (created in step 1), the size of a maximum independent set is at most $m$ (one vertex from each clique). If there is an independent set of size $m$, then there is a satisfying assignment: such an independent set much select exactly one vertex from each clique, and which vertex is selected tells us which variable is used to satisfy that clause. This gives a satisfying assignment because the edges added in step 2 ensure that no conflicting literals are selected. Conversely, it is easy to see how a satisfying assignment corresponds to an independent set of size $m$.

This reduction should give you a good idea of how to approach the case for Vertex Cover (but this will require some slight modifications).